# Label size in directlabels geom_dl()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, font-size, direct-labels

I have really enjoyed the package `directlabels` for dynamic positioning the lables of a plot. Although still not perfect, it helps reasonably to prevent overlaps between labels of a scatter plots with many points for example - specially for the draft version of the charts, not the final one.

However I can not find anyway to change the label size while using `geom_dl()` function. Is there anyway?

I have tried to pass `size` and `cex` as a normal or `aes()` argument to the function.

Comment: reproducible example, please.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put `cex` inside a list. Other formatting features should also be placed in the list. See some of the examples in `?directlabels::geom_dl`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)

dat = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, z = letters[1:10])

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_dl(aes(label = z), method = list(cex = 2, rot = -45, hjust = -.5))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The method too is placed in the list:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_dl(aes(label = z), method = list("smart.grid", cex = 2))
```

Comment: Thanks, when I try to add  geom_dl( aes(label = z), method="smart.grid", list(cex = 1, rot = -45, hjust = -.5)), It says: Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list. Would you please resolve it?

Comment: @AliSharifi, `"smart.grid"` too goes into the list:  `geom_dl(aes(label = z), list("smart.grid", cex = 2))`

Comment: Why does `hjust` work when passed directly to `geom_dl`, while `cex` doesn't?