# How to change font size and colour directlabels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, direct-labels

I have some trouble changing the format of my line labels (colour and size). Can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
colnames(dfm) = c("date", "portfolio", "return")
p1<- ggplot(dfm) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = return, color = portfolio)) +
  geom_dl(aes(x = date, y = return, label = "portfolio"), method = "last.bumpup", size = 0.01, color = portfolio) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 100, linetype = "dashed", color = "blue", size = 0.02) +
  theme_classic()
gt1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
gt1$layout$clip[gt1$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt1)
```

[image: current plot]

Changing the size parameter does not seem to alter the size of the directlabels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242436/label-size-in-directlabels-geom-dl).

Comment: You should always add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise, it's hard to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Label size in directlabels geom\_dl()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242436/label-size-in-directlabels-geom-dl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242436/label-size-in-directlabels-geom-dl), formatting options go inside of a `list` given to the `method` argument.